# Delete empty nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to delete empty nodes, but not all of them, for example I have tags:

```
1.<abc></abc> - it should be delete
2.<cde/> - it should not be delete.
3.<fgh/> - it SHOULD be delete.
```

So, i would like to delete empty nodes in point 2 (explicit name "CDE")

So in other words: when tag like 'cde' and tag is null then delete. : D

Is it possible?

I found the code which delete all the empty nodes:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*[descendant::text() or descendant-or-self::*/@*[string()]]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*[string()]">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT:

XML look like:

```
<system/>
            <smth></smth>
            <smth2>?</smth2>
            <smth3>?</smth3>
            <smth4></smth4>
            <smth4></smth4>
            <smth5/>
```

XML can contain a lot of tags like  - SO i have remove them dynamically.
Some of tags which looks like  I WANT to remove. But in this XML  should stay.

So XML output should looks:

```
 <system/>
                <smth2>?</smth2>
                <smth3>?</smth3>




I found the solution: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/3. : )
```

Comment: Your requirements seem to be contradicting.

Comment: Why? I just DONT want to delete explicit tag. In this case name: CDE.

Comment: But your questions says "2.<cde/> - it should not be delete." and then later on "i would like to delete empty nodes in point 2 (explicit name "CDE")" so the first cited sentence contradicts the second cited one.

Comment: Oh right! Of course.My mistake. I DONT want to delete empty nodes in point 2.  If my xml looks like:  <system/>
            <correlationId></correlationId>
            <enforceExecution>?</enforceExecution>   Output should look like:  <system/>
            <enforceExecution>?</enforceExecution>

Comment: I am afraid this is still not clear. You can either (a) delete all empty nodes except explicitly-named ones, or (b) delete only explicitly-named empty nodes. -- P.S. Please don't post code in comments; edit your question instead.

Comment: I try to delete all empty nodes which looks like <abc></abc> - NOT EXPLICITY.  And some tags which looks like <def/> I would like to remove (explicity-name). So if we have xml input which looks like : <abc></abc> <smth/> <def/> <def>abc</def> . And in code I will explicity indicate that I DONT want to remove SMTH tag, then output should looks like:   <smth/> <def>abc</def>  . Is it possible to do?

Comment: I edit my main question.

Comment: Ok, if it is not possible I can do that by doing 2 different XSL transformation. So, first i would like to delete ALL <tag/> -> how to handle with that?

Comment: @bazylwro Who said it's not possible? I said you're not being clear - and that's still true. Pick either (a) or (b) from the options listed in my previous comment. And give us a valid XML input to work with.

Comment: Helo Michael. Okay, so now we have smth like http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/5. What I'm expecting is <contain><attributes/></contain> is it possible? The rest should be delete

Comment: BTW, try this http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to copy everything but delete empty `cde` elements then use a stylesheet with the following two templates

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cde[not(node())]"/>
```

Comment: Hello Martin. Unfortanely it doesn't work... Is there anything I'm doing wrong? Could you check? http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiKt

Comment: My suggestion as a complete stylesheet is like http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx and not what you have tried.

Comment: Martin thanks. It is almost what i wanted. Is it possible to delete tag which look like <smth></smth> ? Just like here: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/1 . In this case : correlationId . The output should look like now WITHOUT correlationID.

Comment: If you change `<xsl:template match="cde[not(node())]"/>` to `<xsl:template match="cde[not(node())] | correlationId[not(node())]"/>` then empty `correlationId` elements will be removed too.

Comment: Not exactly, I want to remove ALL <abc></abc> (not explicit) , I want to remove some part of <abc/>  tags which I indicate.

Comment: @bazylwro Use `*[not(node()) and name()!='cde']` instead of `cde[not(node())]` in Martin's code.

Comment: Hi Alexander, Unfortanely it still doesn't work. Take a look: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/5 , The output I'm expecting is: <contain><atributes/><contain>. Is it possible?

Comment: I found smth like: http://xsltransform.net/nc4NzRx/6. But it doesnt remove all empty node eg. <SharedGroups>.. : (

Comment: @bazylwro - You wrote _I try to delete **empty** nodes_. <SharedGroups> is not empty!